# The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenu' must be the ID of a control

Tags: 2013, top-link-bar

When I create a new web application in a SharePoint 2013 development farm, I get the below error when I browse the site.

The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found.
[image]

When I check the verbose logs I found:

> DelegateControl: Exception thrown while adding control
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapDataSource':
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Host
>   'www.xxx.xxx.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
>   (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
>   line 288) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Host
>   'www.xxx.xxx.sa' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()      at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()      at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()      at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings)      at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()      at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()      at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()      at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()      at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()      at
>   MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.GetSchemaVersion(String
>   connectionString)      at
>   MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.CheckSchema(String connectionString,
>   NameValueCollection config)      at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings
>   providerSettings, Type providerType)     -  -- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---      at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings
>   providerSettings, Type providerType)      at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection
>   configProviders, ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType)
>   at System.Web.Configuration.SiteMapSection.get_ProvidersInternal()
>   at System.Web.SiteMap.Initialize()      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.get_Provider()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapDataSource.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e)      at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
>   namingContainer)      at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control
>   control, Int32 index)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DelegateControl.AddControlResilient(Control
>   ctl)
>
> System.Web.HttpException: The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenu' must
>   be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control
>   with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found.     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.GetDataSource()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.ConnectToHierarchicalDataSource()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)      at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: are you modified the default master page ?

Comment: yes we modified default master page.

Comment: look in the log files it will be more clear on what is the issue

Comment: please check above logs i pasted in verbose

Answer (score 0):

I think while editing master page you have removed a control which is required.... below is the id of control. try to find the html tag of below control from default master page backup and adding it to your customized master page, it should work.
A control with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found.